# How to create a new heap in OpenJDK?

Tags: java

I want to create a new heap for my project purposes in OpenJDK.
I see the creation of heap in simplegcheap.cpp as

```
Pair<char*, size_t> SimpleGCHeap::allocate_heap_memory(size_t heap_size_in_bytes, size_t align) {
    // Initialize backing storage
    ReservedSpace heap_rs = Universe::reserve_heap(heap_size_in_bytes, align);
    _virtual_space.initialize(heap_rs, heap_size_in_bytes);

    MemRegion committed_region((HeapWord*) (_virtual_space.low()), (HeapWord*) (_virtual_space.high()));
    initialize_reserved_region(committed_region.start(), committed_region.end());

    _space = new ContiguousSpace();
    _space->initialize(committed_region, /* clear_space = */    true, /* mangle_space = */  true);

    return Pair<char*, size_t>(heap_rs.base(), heap_rs.size());
}
```

I modified the code for new_heap as

```
Pair<char*, size_t> SimpleGCHeap::allocate_nheap_memory(size_t heap_size_in_bytes, size_t align) {
    // Initialize backing storage
    ReservedSpace heap_rs = Universe::reserve_heap(heap_size_in_bytes, align);
        _virtual_nspace.initialize(heap_rs, heap_size_in_bytes);

    MemRegion committed_region((HeapWord*) (_virtual_nspace.low()), (HeapWord*) (_virtual_nspace.high()));
    initialize_reserved_region(committed_region.start(), committed_region.end());

    _nspace = new ContiguousSpace();
    _nspace->initialize(committed_region, /* clear_space = */   true, /* mangle_space = */  true);

    return Pair<char*, size_t>(heap_rs.base(), heap_rs.size());
        //return Pair<char*, size_t>(0,0);
}
```

When I call allocate_nheap_memory() anywhere in the code and the if the code reaches the assertion

```
assert(Universe::heap()->is_in_reserved(addr),
"Trying to access bitmap " PTR_FORMAT " for address " PTR_FORMAT " not in the heap.",
p2i(this), p2i(addr));
```

The assertion fails.

How can I create a new heap in OpenJDK?.